# Firebase beforeeach() fires a lot of times (Vue app)

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vue-router

I am building posts app using Firebase and Vue js. I have some issue:
My router:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Dashboard from '@/components/Dashboard'
import Login from '@/components/Login'
import SignUp from '@/components/SingUp'
import RecentPosts from '@/components/RecentPosts';
import firebase from 'firebase'

Vue.use(Router)

let router = new Router({
  routes: [
   ...... some routes
    {
      path: '/recentPosts',
      name: 'RecentPosts',
      component: RecentPosts,
      meta:{
        requireAuth: true
      }
    }
  ]
})
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  let currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  let requiresAuth = to.matched.some(r => r.meta.requiresAuth);
  console.log("CURRENTUSER",currentUser);
  if(!currentUser && requiresAuth) {
    next('Login');
  }else if(currentUser && !requiresAuth) {
    next('Dashboard');
  }else if (currentUser && requiresAuth) {
    next();
  }else {
    next();
  }
});
export default router;
```

After i go to `/recentPosts` my function beforeeach fires so many times so that it blocks my app.
Why I cant access /recentPosts ? I have logged in user so it should resolve my rout, but it's not.

```
else if (currentUser && requiresAuth) {
    next();
}
```

It should resolbe my '/recentsposts' route, but it isn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably because you have a typo at `require(s)`:

```
    {
      path: '/recentPosts',
      name: 'RecentPosts',
      component: RecentPosts,
      meta:{
        requireAuth: true     // <- without "s" at the end of require
      }
    }
  ]
})
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  let currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  let requiresAuth = to.matched.some(r => r.meta.requiresAuth);   // <- with an "s" at the end of requires
```